# How do I have Python accept each value when setting a class attribute as a lambda property?

Tags: python

I'm running into a silly issue that I can't figure out. If I assign an attribute to a lambda function via `setattr` in a for loop, it will assign **all** the attributes the same value as that which was passed in the last iteration of the loop. Can anyone shed some light on this?

```python
class bee(object):
    def __init__(self):
        def say_my_name (self, name):
            return name

        setattr(bee, f'Jim_name', property(lambda self: say_my_name(self, 'Jim')))
        setattr(bee, f'Jill_name', property(lambda self: say_my_name(self, 'Jill')))

        for name in ['Jake', 'Jordan']:
            setattr(bee, f'{name}_name', property(lambda self: say_my_name(self, name)))

buzz = bee()

print(buzz.Jim_name)
# >Jim

print(buzz.Jill_name)
# >Jill

print(buzz.Jake_name)
# >Jordan
# Should be Jake!

print(buzz.Jordan_name)
# >Jordan
```

Comment: `name` is a free variable; lookup doesn't occur until the getter is called, not when the getter is defined.

Comment: Why are you repeatedly (re)creating instance-specific properties every time `__init__` is called, anyway?

Comment: Because in the full code the attributes are dynamically created and the property does a lot more fancy stuff.

Comment: Do you ever create more than once instance of `bee`? If you do, you are unnecessarily recreating the properties each time you create an instance. If not, I wonder if you *should* be.